# How do you get the nonce value in an MVC.NET App?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In the research that I have done there is an oAuth library out there, but I guess this isn't in System.Web or System.Web.MVC etc. If using the nonce value is the correct way to prevent relay attacks and the preferred method to prevent duplicate form submissions it would seem like there would be an out of box solution to get at this value.

Any input would be helpful.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I don't quite understand what your objective is. Are you looking for an OOTB authentication/authorization system? or what?

Comment: i think he's asking how to retrieve the nonce key, which is solution to prevent the user from double clicking a submit button causing duplicate posts to occur.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to stop a form post happening twice. Based on the info in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888965. I got the javascript in place, but I don't know how to get at this nonce value to handle it on the server side. I can generate my own key, but I don't think that would stop the relay attacks from happening. I have never heard of this value before today so I was curious too.

Comment: I can't believe there is actually seriously really something called the nonce value. brilliant.