# Prevent multiple POST in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I prevent the user from posting the same data to the action multiple times if they keep clicking the submit button?

I know in php, there is a way to prevent this multiple submission, but I do not see any for asp.net mvc. Is there any?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888965/what-methods-are-available-to-stop-multiple-postbacks-of-a-form-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent double form submissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803286/prevent-double-form-submissions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could disable the submit button using javascript. Example with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#idofsubmitbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Note however that this might not be 100% reliable as for example the user could have javascript disabled or even worse: he could have malicious intents and automate HTTP POST requests.

Comment: This is always a good thing to do, but it's not foolproof, especially if your user is malicious.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, of course. I should have mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: So should I make this generic for all forms across the site?

Comment: @Lol coder, yes, you could do this for all forms that invoke actions modifying state on the server.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [Post-Redirect-Get Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Disabling the Submit button doesn't prevent F5 refreshes.

Comment: While the PRG pattern is good and should be used, if the P action in it takes time (which is usually the case) the user can click on the submit button once again and initiate a second call to this action with the same data as the first.

Comment: we use both PRG and disable approach in combination to avoid this problem provided javascript is not disabled

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to implement PRG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern, I have an old post on this subject on aspnet mvc http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx check the #13.

Comment: While the PRG pattern is good and should be used, if the `P` action in it takes time (which is usually the case) the user can click on the submit button once again and initiate a second call to this action with the same data as the first.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803286/prevent-double-form-submissions/36860136#36860136), but I post my answer here for easy reference...

The PRG pattern will not prevent this, as the P action in it takes time (which is usually the case) and the user can submit the form again (via click or browser refresh), which will cause the PRG pattern to "fail".

Note that malicious users can also bypass all of your client side measures by running multiple http posts in quick succession.

A solution to all of the above is to check for duplicate submissions on server side using the following method, as described by myself, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927647/prevent-double-submit-post-on-asp-net-mvc-page/36839133#36839133).

I quote:

> "If you make use of a hidden anti-forgery token in your form (as you
>   should), you can cache the anti-forgery token on first submit and
>   remove the token from cache if required, or expire the cached entry
>   after set amount of time."
>
> You will then be able to check with each request against the cache
>   whether the specific form has been submitted and reject it if it has."