# Prevent double form submissions

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application which has a post action called `Create`:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Create(Issues issues)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Issues.Add(issues);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(issues);
}
```

If I double click on the submit button by mistake, it'll Create 2x issues. Is there a way of preventing this, without the use of javascript and disabling the button, I thought the whole use of using a `RedirectToAction` was to prevent this, by using the Post/Redirect/Get design pattern?

Comment: can you simply add something like if(!context.Issues.Exists(logic))?

Comment: Just disable the submit button when clicked!

Comment: There is no such method called Exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern you mentioned (Post/Redirect/Get design pattern) prevents page refreshes from double posting because the last action is a GET, not the POST.

If you want to prevent double clicks from double posting, you could:

> ```
> 1. Disable the button after click
> 2. Maintain a unique index on 'Issues' and look for duplicates
> 3. Maintain something in session that gives you an indication of a double post
> ```

And there maybe a few more ways... I think disabling the button is probably the easiest because you're redirecting to another page anyway.

Comment: This is fine for the above example, but the point I was getting at is for more advanced examples, for example Ajax.BeginForm which'll only update part of a page

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff - To prevent double clicking on the client side (AJAX POST), you could simply block the UI until the response comes back (synchronous), or disable the button (asynchronous), or implement something server-side to detect it.

Comment: Hi Chris, this is exactly what I have done now. I've disabled the button untill the response has come back. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

Easy solution!

Disable the submit button when it's clicked. *The End.*

```
$('submitButtonId').click(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // for jQuery versions < 1.6.
});
```

Comment: With this solution, if the user has a network problem in between the click and uploading the information to the server, then there's no way to salvage the information in the form. If the user just spent 5 minutes filling out the form they'll be upset.  A better approach is probably to only disable it until the network succeeds or fails.

Comment: @AlexAngas, nothing will work when javascript is disabled. I don't think there's a good way of doing it without js.  (_Shadow Wizard_ answer below is hard coding 1000 ms, which is far from being ideal, what if the user has slow network connection?)

Answer (score 2):

Most simple way I can think of is use the Session:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if (Session["LastAdd"] == null || (now - (DateTime)Session["LastAdd"]).TotalMilliseconds > 1000)
    {
        //first time, or more than a second passed since last addition
        context.Issues.Add(issues);
        context.SaveChanges();
        Session["LastAdd"] = now;
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I dont use sessions as its a Windows Authentication application

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff - Start using `Session` variables.

Comment: @Biff Session variables got nothing to do with authentication. what makes you think this way?

Comment: I just thought that Sessions were used with Forms Authentication

Comment: @Biff nope. It's integral part of any web application, starting back in classic ASP. Forms Authentication might be using Session to track the user and keep him logged in but it's like you'll say that `string` only exists in Windows Forms applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an IssueId when you show the form to the user, then check that you don't already have an issue with such id in your Create method and, for example, skip such requests.

Comment: Well it'll just create keep appending Id's as IssueId is my PK field so for every new Issue created, it'll have a new Id (2, 3, 4, 5 etc..)

Answer (score 0):

The PRG pattern will not prevent this, as the P action in it takes time (which is usually the case) and the user can submit the form again (via click or browser refresh), which will cause the PRG pattern to "fail".

Note that malicious users can also bypass all of your client side measures by running multiple http posts in quick succession.

A solution to all of the above is to check for duplicate submissions on server side using the following method, as described by myself, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27927647/prevent-double-submit-post-on-asp-net-mvc-page/36839133#36839133).

For your convenience, I quote:

> "If you make use of a hidden anti-forgery token in your form (as you
>   should), you can cache the anti-forgery token on first submit and
>   remove the token from cache if required, or expire the cached entry
>   after set amount of time.
>
> You will then be able to check with each request against the cache
>   whether the specific form has been submitted and reject it if it has."